# css is not being applied on jodit editor with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, jodit

css is not being applied to jodit in react, and i can't figure out why, examples:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fpu2.jpg

and when scrolling down:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9cqn.jpg

my code is simple:

```
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

function Comp(){
return(

<div> <JoditEditor></JoditEditor> </div>     ) }
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue switched to class component now working fine. Similar to below code.

```
import React from 'react';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";

class Comp extends React.Component {

render() {
  return <div> <JoditEditor></JoditEditor> </div>
 }
}
export default Comp;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).